# Computing the dual of an LP with equality constraints

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

I am having a linear program in the form :
\begin{cases}
\min_x\ \ -5x_1 + 27.5x_2 + 4.5x_3 + 12x_4\ \ \mathrm{s.t.}\ \\ \ \\
\qquad\qquad     0.25x_1 − 2.75x_2 − 1.25x_3 + 4.5x_4 + 0.5x_5 = 0\\
\qquad\qquad     0.25x_1 - 0.75x_2 -0.25x_3 +0.5x_4 + 0.5x_6=0\\
\qquad\qquad     0.5x_1 + 0.5x_7 = 0.5\\
\qquad\qquad     x_i \geq 0 \; \forall i 
\end{cases}
I am trying to compute the dual.

In Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_linear_program is mentioned that:

- I need to introduce m = 3 dual variables (m is the number of constraints ) $y_1, y_2, y_3$ and for constraints in the form of "$..=b_i$" I am going to introduce a non-sign constraint : $y_i \in R$.
- The objective function will be : $ \max \sum_{i = 1}^m b_i y_i $
- I create n constraints in the form  $\sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij} = c_i $ where " $\geq c_i $" (instead of $= , \leq$ comes from $x_i \geq 0 $)

  $\begin{cases}
  \max y_3\\
  0.25y_1 + 0.25y_2 + 0.5y_3 \geq -5\\
  -2.75y_1 - 0.75y_2 \geq 27.5\\
  -1.25y_1 -0.25y_2 \geq 4.5\\
  4.5y_1 + 0.5y_2 \geq 12\\
  y_1 \geq 0 \\
  y_2 \geq 0 \\
  y_3 \geq 0 
  \end{cases}$

The last 3 constaints do not agree with what wiki says about $y_i \in R$

Comment: In the case of equality constraints, your Lagrange multipliers do not need to be nonnegative. So, you need to remove the three last inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four errors:

1. Your objective coefficient $1$ conflicts with $b_3=0.5$.
2. Because $x_i\ge 0$, the dual constraints should be $\le$ instead of $=$.
3. Because the primal constraints are $=$, the dual variables $y_i$ should be free instead of $\ge 0$.
4. You need three more dual constraints, corresponding to $x_5$, $x_6$, and $x_7$.

You might find the [S-O-B method](https://math.hmc.edu/benjamin/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2019/06/Sensible-Rules-for-Remembering-Duals%E2%80%93The-S-O-B-Method.pdf) useful.

Comment: how I am going to find the extra dual constraints?

Comment: By looking at the coefficients of each of those three variables in the primal problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have many mistakes in writing dual model. Dual is

\begin{align}
\max \quad&   0y_1+0y_2+0.5y_3 \\
\text{s.t.} \quad& 0.25y_1+0.25y_2+0.5y_3 \le -5 \\
& -2.75y_1-0.75y_2+0y_3 \le 27.5 \\
& -1.25y_1-0.25y_2+0y_3 \le 4.5 \\
& 4.5y_1+0.5y_2 +0y_3 \le 12 \\
& 0.5y_1+0y_2+0y_3 \le 0 \\
& 0y_1+0.5y_2+0y_3 \le 0 \\
& 0y_1+0y_2+0.5y_3 \le 0 \\
& y_i \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}